# Source moving at speed of sound

Tags: sound

What frequency sound would be observed by observer at rest is source is moving away from him at speed of sound?
And Why so?

Answer (score 2):

This can be derived from the doppler frequency shift equation with reference to a stationary observer.

f = f'(v/v+v')

where:

- v is the speed of sound in a medium
- v' is the speed of the source
- f' is the source frequency
- f is the apparent frequency

if the speed of the source (v') equals the speed of sound (v) then the equation folds down to:

f = f'(v/2v) = f'/2

Answer (score 1):

Half the original frequency.  If you listen to the sound that is happening 1 second later, it arrives with an additional delay of 1 second due to the sound propagation.  So the phase moves forward at half the original speed.